# How can I patchValue with FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I need to patchValue from Api in this formControl

**".html"**

```
`<p-dialog header="แก้ไขห้องพัก" [(visible)]="displayEdit" [modal]=true [style]="{width: '30vw'}"><div class="row" [formGroup]="edtForm">
  <input pInputText type="hidden" formControlName="id_room" [attr.disabled]="true">
  <input pInputText type="hidden" formControlName="id_roomDetail" [attr.disabled]="true">
  <input pInputText type="hidden" formControlName="homestayID" [attr.disabled]="true">
  <div class="col-5 text-right">เลขที่ห้อง :</div>
  <div class="col-7"><input pInputText type="text" formControlName="numRoom" [attr.disabled]="true"></div>
  <div class="col-5 text-right">Name :</div>
  <div class="col-7">
  <p-dropdown id="homestayName" formControlName="homestayName" [options]="homestays"></p-dropdown>
 </div>
</p-dialog>`
```

**".ts"**

```
this.roomService.queryRoomById(id).subscribe((res) => {
    const data = {
      ...res
    };
    this.edtForm.patchValue(data);
  });
```

and service is

```
queryRoomById(id: string) {
return this.http.get<Rooms>('http://localhost/taladnoi/api/api_getRoomAdmin.php?id=' + id);
```

}

Comment: The patch value matches with the control name. Check if the property names from the api are the same as your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what your API returns, but the patch on a form is just updating values of parts of your form.

I see you have a couple of form controls:

- id_room
- id_roomDetail
- homestayID
- numRoom
- homestayName

Let's say you want to update the `numRoom` field, you'd do something similar like this:

```js
this.formName.pathValue({ numRoom: newValue });
```